# Change space between lines in tick labels

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I need to implement a new "graphic generator". To ilustrate this requirement, I'll show an example of output using the old generator and the output of the one I'm trying to develop (or where I got so far).

[image: Old generator output example]

[image: New generator output example]

My main issue right now is the space between the lines on the tick labels. The image must be 600x150, so I need to compress the text part of the graphic as much as I can (It doesn't need to be visually beautiful), but I could not find any suitable code so far.

Actually I need to eliminate as much "white spacing" as I can. If anyone have a hint how to implement the following, I would really appreciate:

- Remove white gap between chart tittle and chart itself;
- Remove white gap between tick labels and the bottow end of the image;
- Remove the light gray line that represent the ticks on the bottom part of the chart. Right now the ticks labels and this line are overlapping.

This is the code I'm using to customize the chart:

```
CategoryPlot categoryplot = lineChart.getCategoryPlot();
    lineChart.setTitle(
        new org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle(lineChart.getTitle().getText(),
            new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10)
        )
     );
    lineChart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    categoryplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    CategoryAxis domainAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(4); 
    categoryplot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
    Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 8);
    categoryplot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(font);
    categoryplot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositionOffset(-6);
    categoryplot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelInsets(
        new RectangleInsets(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
    NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) categoryplot.getRangeAxis();
    yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    categoryplot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(
        1, 
        new BasicStroke(
            2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
            1.0f, new float[] {6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
        )
    );        
    categoryplot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
    categoryplot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
    categoryplot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
    categoryplot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
    categoryplot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(
        2, 
        new BasicStroke(
            2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
            1.0f, new float[] {6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
        )
    );
    categoryplot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
    categoryplot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.RED);
    categoryplot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2, Color.RED);
    LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) categoryplot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
    renderer.setDrawOutlines(true);
    renderer.setUseFillPaint(true);
    renderer.setBaseFillPaint(Color.white);
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-5, -5, 10, 10));
```